# jump back into vim directory browser after closing a file

Tags: vim

vim is able to open directories (and then browse in them).

```
vim roles/webservices/tasks/
```

```
" ============================================================================
" Netrw Directory Listing                                        (netrw v156)
"   /home/gwagner/repos/automation_postgres/roles/webservices/tasks
"   Sorted by      name
"   Sort sequence: [\/]$,\<core\%(\.\d\+\)\=\>,\.h$,\.c$,\.cpp$,\~\=\*$,*,\.o$,\.obj$,\.info$,\.swp$,\.bak$,\~$
"   Quick Help: <F1>:help  -:go up dir  D:delete  R:rename  s:sort-by  x:special
" ==============================================================================
../
./
download_file.yml
main.yml
post_data.yml
post_du.yml
~
```

Now, is it possible to jump back into the directory browser inside vim when closing a file?
`:wq`, `:q`, `:x` throws you back into the bash to where you came from

Comment: you must make a macro for that   in default commands there is no such function as far as I know

Comment: ok, thx. That is way beyond my capabilites though. Maybe I'll al least file a feature request for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `:Explore` will open the directory listing.

From `:help :Explore` (`vim 9.0`):

```
DIRECTORY EXPLORATION COMMANDS  {{{2

     :[N]Explore[!]  [dir]... Explore directory of current file      *:Explore*
     :[N]Hexplore[!] [dir]... Horizontal Split & Explore             *:Hexplore*
     :[N]Lexplore[!] [dir]... Left Explorer Toggle                   *:Lexplore*
     :[N]Sexplore[!] [dir]... Split&Explore current file's directory *:Sexplore*
     :[N]Vexplore[!] [dir]... Vertical   Split & Explore             *:Vexplore*
     :Texplore       [dir]... Tab & Explore                          *:Texplore*
     :Rexplore            ... Return to/from Explorer                *:Rexplore*

     Used with :Explore **/pattern : (also see |netrw-starstar|)
     :Nexplore............. go to next matching file                *:Nexplore*
     :Pexplore............. go to previous matching file            *:Pexplore*

                        *netrw-:Explore*
:Explore  will open the local-directory browser on the current file's
          directory (or on directory [dir] if specified).  The window will be
      split only if the file has been modified and |'hidden'| is not set,
      otherwise the browsing window will take over that window.  Normally
      the splitting is taken horizontally.
      Also see: |netrw-:Rexplore|
:Explore! is like :Explore, but will use vertical splitting.
```